# The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget _buildDropDownButton(String currencyCategory) {
return DropdownButton(
  value: currencyCategory,
  items: currencies
      .map((String value) => DropdownMenuItem(
    value: value,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(value),
      ],
    ),
  ))
      .toList(),
  onChanged: (String value) {
    if(currencyCategory == fromCurrency){
      _onFromChanged(value);
    }else {
      _onToChanged(value);
    }
  },
);
```

}

Hi, I have an issue in this part of sample code, in this part of code:

```
      onChanged: (String value) {
    if(currencyCategory == fromCurrency){
      _onFromChanged(value);
    }else {
      _onToChanged(value);
    }
  },
```

It shows an error `The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'`

I tried placing `final void Function() onChanged;` or `final VoidCallback onChanged;` but it expects and identifier. Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Your methods assigned to `onChanged` needs to take `String?` as argument since the parameter can be `null`. The error message are telling you that the provided method has the signature of `void Function(String)` but it expect a method with the signature `void Function(String?)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the null safety, the value for the dropdown can be null when nothing is selected. Add a "?" after the String type declaration to be like `onChanged(String? value) {//on change logic}`.

Checkout the flutter [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html#material.DropdownButton.1) example.